# Find data which may be added to the firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android project where I am using firebase database.

The problem is that i want to check for a particular data which may exist after sometime in the database.

For a clarification, there are two users in firebase, 1) Prem, 2) Suraj. When Prem clicks on a button "Send requests" then Suraj gets Prem's request now if Suraj clicks on that request then the firebase data base makes a child "Playing" which contains - "Prem:Suraj" and now from Prem's side i want to check if Suraj has clicked on that request so i thought it would be best to see if that data exists but its not working because the data will be existing in future and not in the current time.

If anyone could help me, i'll be really grateful.

```
`//Sender Side

private void confirmRequestTo(final String OtherPlayer) {
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connecting_players, null);
b.setView(dialogView);
 
b.setTitle("Start Game?");
b.setMessage("Connect with " + OtherPlayer );
b.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                myRef.child("Users").child(OtherPlayer).child("request").push().setValue(LoginUserID); //Sending the Request
                Toast.makeText(Request_InterfaceActivity.this, "Waiting For " + OtherPlayer + " to Join", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Request_InterfaceActivity.help = true;


                //Waiting for the Request to be Accepted
                String pid = UserName + ":" + OtherPlayer;
                DatabaseReference playref = myRef.child("Playing");

                int sum = 100;

                for(int i =0; i<sum;i++) {
                    playref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < sum; j++) {
                                if (snapshot.hasChild(UserName + ":" + OtherPlayer)) {
                                    StartGame(UserName + ":" + OtherPlayer, OtherPlayer, "TO");


                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Request_InterfaceActivity.this, UserName + ":" + OtherPlayer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }

                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        }).setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Request_InterfaceActivity.help = false;

            }
        });

        b.show();

    }



//Receiver Side
    private void confirmRequestFrom(final String OtherPlayer) {

        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connecting_players, null);
        b.setView(dialogView);

        b.setTitle("Start Game?");
        b.setMessage("Connect with " + OtherPlayer );

        b.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                StartGame(OtherPlayer + ":" + UserName, OtherPlayer, "From");

            }
        });

        b.setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        b.show();

    }

    private void StartGame(String PlayerGameID, String OtherPlayer, String requestType) {
        //To Implement Later
        myRef.child("Playing").child(PlayerGameID).removeValue();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OnlineGameActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("PlayerSession", PlayerGameID);
        i.putExtra("Username", UserName);
        i.putExtra("OtherPlayer", OtherPlayer);
        i.putExtra("LoginUID", LoginUID);
        i.putExtra("RequestType", requestType);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

        myRef.getRoot().child("Users").orderByKey().equalTo(UserName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postsnapshot :snapshot.getChildren()){

                    String key = myRef.child("Users").child(UserName).getKey();
                    myRef.child("Users").child(key).removeValue();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }`
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using Firestore?  If so, you should be using Listeners on the documents you care about to immediately detect changes that you might be interested in.  Polling the database to detect a change from another user is not the way to go.

Comment: @AlexMamo, Sir I have shared the particular code. Can you help me know the mistakes or improvisation I can make.

Comment: @Larry Sir, I am using the firebase realtime database. Yes I am using the Listener but still not getting the desired output I want.